# How do I tail the logs of ALL my docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can tail the logs of a single docker container by doing:

```
docker logs -f container1
```

But, how can I tail the logs of multiple containers on the same screen?

```
docker logs container1 container2
```

doesn’t work. It gives an error:

```
“docker logs” requires exactly 1 argument(s).
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `docker logs` command can't stream multiple logs files.

`docker-compose logs -f` can stream logs for a project

#### Logging Drivers

You could use one of the [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) other than the default `json` to ship the logs to a common point. The systemd [`journald`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/) or [`syslog`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/syslog/) drivers would readily work on most systems. Any of the other centralised log systems would work too.

Note that configuring  `syslog` on the Docker daemon means that `docker logs` command can no longer query the logs, they will only be stored where your syslog puts them.

A simple `daemon.json` for syslog:

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
    "syslog-address": "tcp://10.8.8.8:514",
    "syslog-format": "rfc5424"
  }
}
```

#### API

You could write tool that [attaches to each container via the API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerAttach) and streams the logs via a websocket. Two of the Java libararies are [docker-client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client) and [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java).

#### Hack

Or run multiple `docker logs` and munge the output, in node.js:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function run(id){
  let dkr = spawn('docker', [ 'logs', '--tail', '1', '-t', '--follow', id ])
  dkr.stdout.on('data', data => console.log('%s: stdout', id, data.toString().replace(/\r?\n$/,'')))
  dkr.stderr.on('data', data => console.error('%s: stderr', id, data.toString().replace(/\r?\n$/,'')))
  dkr.on('close', exit_code => {
    if ( exit_code !== 0 ) throw new Error(`Docker logs ${id} exited with ${exit_code}`)
  })
}

let args = process.argv.splice(2)
args.forEach(arg => run(arg))
```

Which dumps data as `docker logs` writes it.

```
○→ node docker-logs.js 958cc8b41cd9 1dad69882b3d db4b844d9478
958cc8b41cd9: stdout 2018-03-01T06:37:45.152010823Z hello2
1dad69882b3d: stdout 2018-03-01T06:37:49.392475996Z hello
db4b844d9478: stderr 2018-03-01T06:37:47.336367247Z hello2
958cc8b41cd9: stdout 2018-03-01T06:37:55.155137606Z hello2
db4b844d9478: stderr 2018-03-01T06:37:57.339710598Z hello2
1dad69882b3d: stdout 2018-03-01T06:37:59.393960369Z hello
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using docker-compose, this will show all logs from the diferent containers

```
docker-compose logs -f
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have access and root to the docker server:

```
tail -f  /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
```

Comment: This solution is better suited for a temporary access. The chosen answer is better for a permanent solution.

Comment: `tail -f /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log`